# Which of "have I messed up" or "did I mess up" is more appropriate?

Tags: idiomatic-language, phrase-choice

> I think your soon-to-be wife is a jerk, ok? There I said it. I won't lie to you. (a moment) So, **have I messed up now** or am I still invited to the wedding?
>
> I think your soon-to-be wife is a jerk, ok? There I said it. I won't lie to you. (a moment) So, **did I mess up now** or am I still invited to the wedding?

Is "have I messed up now" or "did I mess up now" more appropriate in this context?

Answer (score 1):

"Have I messed up now?" fits the situation perfectly. The other form is possible, but it doesn't fit as well. The present perfect, along with "now", makes it an obvious reference to the immediate past.

Comment: I think Americans would be more inclined to use 'Did I?' where British English would use 'Have I [done]?'

Answer (score 1):

In American spoken English, the second example, "did I mess up now" is more common. "Have I messed up now" sounds too formal.

Nevertheless, both are equally acceptable.